# Applovin Template native ad in recycler view adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, applovin

I need help implementing Applovin native ads in recycler view. I cannot find any references on how to implement app lovin native template ads in recycler view adapter.

The Code to implement native ads in activity is :

```
 public class ExampleActivity extends Activity
{
    private MaxNativeAdLoader nativeAdLoader;
    private MaxAd             nativeAd;

    void createNativeAd()
    {
        FrameLayout nativeAdContainer = findViewById( R.id.native_ad_layout );

        nativeAdLoader = new MaxNativeAdLoader( "YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID", this );
        nativeAdLoader.setNativeAdListener( new MaxNativeAdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onNativeAdLoaded(final MaxNativeAdView nativeAdView, final MaxAd ad)
            {
                // Clean up any pre-existing native ad to prevent memory leaks.
                if ( nativeAd != null )
                {
                    nativeAdLoader.destroy( nativeAd );
                }

                // Save ad for cleanup.
                nativeAd = ad;

                // Add ad view to view.
                nativeAdContainer.removeAllViews();
                nativeAdContainer.addView( nativeAdView );
            }

            @Override
            public void onNativeAdLoadFailed(final String adUnitId, final MaxError error)
            {
                // We recommend retrying with exponentially higher delays up to a maximum delay
            }

            @Override
            public void onNativeAdClicked(final MaxAd ad)
            {
                // Optional click callback
            }
        } );

        nativeAdLoader.loadAd();
    }
}
```

How can I add this in my recycler view adapter and show ads?
I have searched everywhere on internet but could not find any references how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After the last Applovin update to 11.4.0, the implementation of the recyclerview is done.

This is the link to the official document: https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/getting-started/native-ad-placer

I enclose the code that I have used and it has worked for the small and medium template, I have not been able to implement the manual template since the ads are not published. Hope this can help you.

```
MaxAdPlacerSettings settings = new MaxAdPlacerSettings("Ad Unit ID");
settings.setRepeatingInterval(2);
MaxRecyclerAdapter adAdapter = new MaxRecyclerAdapter(settings, yourcurrentadapter, this);
listview.setAdapter(adAdapter);
adAdapter.loadAds();
```